# Convert org.hibernate.Query to org.hibernate.Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to convert `org.hibernate.Query` to `org.hibernate.Criteria`? How can I achieve that?

I have a named query, and will be loading it to a `org.hibernate.Query`, but I might need to add some filtering to it, that's why I need to convert this query to a `org.hibernate.Criteria`

What I want is something like this: (example code)

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("myNamedQuery");
Criteria criteria = session.convertQueryToCriteria(query);
```